# Laravel, Vue with axios Login page with a verified check will stop working after the second try

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-sanctum

I have build a Laravel, Vue, sanctum with axios Login page with a verified check but it will stop working after the second try.

This issue will ocure when I use a user that is present with matching credits but this user must be verified so it should return false when he/she is not verified but when trying this it will stop working after the second try and axios returns (as json) the document markup.

I do see that it ads a couple of cookies and when I remove these it will work again. For what I can see it is the sessions cookie that prevents axios from working

```
   public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->validator($request->all())->fails()) {
            // errors, this works perfect
        } else {
            $credentials = [
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ];

            if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                if (Auth::user()->verified === null) {    

                    Session::flush():// this solves the issue

                    // not verified
                    $success = false;
                    ...
                } else {

                    // we have a match
                    $success = true;
                    ...
                }
            } else {

                //no match
                $success = false;
                ...              
            }

            $response = [
                'success' => $success,
                 ...
            ];
        }

        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

vue component

```
  methods: {    
        async login(e){
            const data = {
                email : this.fields.email,
                password : this.fields.password
            }
            try{
                await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
                await axios.post('/api/login', data).then((res) => {
                    if (res.data.success) {                        
                        //working and redirect to the home page
                    } else {     
                        //errors                                        
                    }
                }).catch((e) => {
                    throw e.response
                });
            } catch (e) {
                throw e
            }       
        }
}
```

bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');
    
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.MIX_APP_URL;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
   'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Accept': 'application/json'
};

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->validator($request->all())->fails()) {
            // errors, this works perfect
        } else {
            $credentials = [
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ];

            if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                if (Auth::user()->verified === null) {
```

// not verified
return $failed= true;
...
} else {

```
                // we have a match
                $success = true;
                    ...
                } else {

                    // we have a match
                    $success = true;
                    ...
                }
            } else {

                //no match
                $success = false;
                ...              
            }

            $response = [
                'success' => $success,
                 ...
            ];
        }

        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

instead of returning success true and false change to another variable `($failed)` then your vue will differentiate with success. and return to else statement. there create a page to redirect all unverified user.

In your vue js Login.vue now

```
data(){
        return{
            form:{
                email: '',
                password: '',
                device_name: 'browser'
            },
            errors: {} //define errors in data
        }
    },
   methods: {
            async login(e){
                const data = {
                    email : this.fields.email,
                    password : this.fields.password
                }
                try{
                    await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
                    await axios.post('/api/login', data).then((res) => {
                         if (res.data.success) {                        
                    //working and redirect to the home page
                } else {     
                    //redirect to not verified page                                      
                }
                    }).catch((e) => {
                        throw e.response
                    });
                } 
            }
    }
```

Vue will catch the error so no need of if and else statement. I hope it works

Comment: no the issue is that laravel will set a session cookie once the users has logged in. This cookie will prevent axios from working. Another issue is that laravel will set this cookie if the user is not verified yet

Comment: I use the same logic with vue and laravel sanctum but I used token method instead of sanctum cookie. I will edit the answer and see if this works for you

Comment: I found a fix and this is adding a session flush but this isnt the way to do this.